# Can you compile ffmpeg with VVC/VTM encoder/decoder support?

Tags: ffmpeg

Since VVC has now been finalized I want to test encoding with it.

Is it possible to compile ffmpeg with it? And if not, is there already a request ticket for that open (can't find any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not published, yet!

According to the Frauenhofer HHI newsletter

> (...) Dr. Thomas Schierl, head of the Video Coding and Analytics department
> at Fraunhofer HHI, announced “this autumn Fraunhofer HHI will publish
> the first software (for both encoder and decoder) to support
> H.266/VVC.”

https://newsletter.fraunhofer.de/-viewonline2/17386/465/11/14SHcBTt/V44RELLZBp/1

Comment: Actually there's already an encoder and decoder available which makes me wonder why they said something like this: [Gitlab Frauenhofer](https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/VVCSoftware_VTM) 

The Encoder and Decoder is not really user friendly though and as a reason I would love to implement it in ffmpeg.

Comment: it needs to be implemented in libvacodec which is a part of ffmpeg. This lib is implementing GNU licenced sourcecode from x264.org and x265.org for 264/265 en/decoding. Until today there is no x266 sourcecode for libvacodec - ffmpeg won't encode it and vlc  won't decode/play it until it's released.